# Error in Cart Page while updating product quantity

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, axios

Please **help** me with my REACT problem. On the cart page, while I try to increase the quantity or decrease the number of quantity products, I get this type of error. I have attached the error in the **Image**. **Please see the Image.**

[image]

Here's My Code:
**Cart.js**. Trying to update the product quantity on the cart page. But getting errors as you see in the picture.

```
import React, { Fragment } from 'react';
import "./Cart.css";
import CartItemCard from "./CartItemCard";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux'
import { addItemsToCart } from '../../action/cartAction';


const Cart = () => {

    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const { cartItems } = useSelector((state) => state.cart);

    const increaseQuantity = (id, quantity, stock) => {

        const newQty = quantity + 1 ;
        if(stock <= quantity) {
            return;
        }

        dispatch(addItemsToCart(id, newQty));

    };

    const decreaseQuantity = (id, quantity) => {

        const newQty = quantity - 1 ;
        if (1 >= quantity) {
            return;
        }

        dispatch(addItemsToCart(id, newQty));

    };

    return (

        <Fragment>
            <div className="cartPage">
                <div className="cartHeader">
                    <p>Product</p>
                    <p>Quantity</p>
                    <p>Subtotal</p>
                </div>


                {cartItems && cartItems.map((item) => (
                                    <div className="cartContainer" key={item.product} >

                                    <CartItemCard item={item}  />
                                    <div className="cartInput">
                                        <button  onClick={() => decreaseQuantity(item.product, item.quantity)} > - </button>
                                        <input type="number" readOnly value={item.quantity} />
                                        <button onClick={() => increaseQuantity(item.product, item.quantity, item.stock)} > + </button>
                                    </div>
                
                                    <p className="cartSubtotal">{`$${item.price*item.quantity}`}</p>
                
                
                                </div>
                ))}

                <div className="cartGrossTotal">

                    <div></div>

                    <div className="cartGrossTotalBox">
                        <p>Gross Total</p>
                        <p>{`$600`}</p>
                    </div>

                    <div></div>

                    <div className="checkOutBtn">
                        <button>Check Out</button>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>

        </Fragment>
    );
};

export default Cart;
```

Here's the Action:
**cartAction.js**

```
import {ADD_TO_CART} from "../constants/cartConstants";
import axios from "axios";


export const addItemsToCart = (id, quantity) => async (dispatch,getState) => {

    const { data } = await axios.get(`/api/v1/product/${id}`);
    
    dispatch({
        type: ADD_TO_CART,
        payload: {
            product: data.product._id,
            name: data.product.name,
            price: data.product.price,
            image: data.product.images[0].url,
            stock: data.product.Stock,
            quantity,
        },
    });

    localStorage.setItem("cartItems",JSON.stringify(getState().cart.cartItems)); 
    
};
```

Cart Reducer Code.
**CartReducer:**

```
import {ADD_TO_CART} from "../constants/cartConstants";


export const cartReducer = (state = { cartItems: [] }, action ) => {

    switch (action.type) {
        case ADD_TO_CART:
            
            
        const item = action.payload;

        const isItemExist = state.cartItems.find(
            (i) => i.product === item.product
        );

        if(isItemExist) {
            return {
                ...state,
                cartItems: state.cartItems.map((i) =>
                i.product === isItemExist.product ? true : i

                ),
            };

        } else {

            return{
                ...state,
                cartItems: [...state.cartItems, item],
            };

        }

 
        default:
            return state;
    }

};
```

React Store.
**Store:**

```
import { createStore,combineReducers,applyMiddleware } from "redux";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";

import { composeWithDevTools } from "@redux-devtools/extension";
import { productDetailsReducer, producReducer } from "./reducers/productReducer";
import { forgotPasswordReducer, profileReducer, userReducer } from "./reducers/userReducer";
import { cartReducer } from "./reducers/cartReducer";


const reducer = combineReducers({
    products: producReducer,
    productDetails: productDetailsReducer,
    user: userReducer,
    profile: profileReducer,
    forgotPassword: forgotPasswordReducer,
    cart: cartReducer,

});

let initialState = {
    cart: {
        cartItems: localStorage.getItem("cartItems")
            ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("cartItems"))
            : [],
    }
};

const middleware = [thunk]

const store = createStore(
                    reducer,
                    initialState,
                    composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(...middleware)
                ));

export default store;
```

Comment: please post them on codesandbox and send the link

Comment: `id` is undefined. What is `item.product` that is passed to the handlers? If all 3 arguments come from an item object, why not just pass `item` to the handler?

Comment: @DrewReese item.product is the product coming from store state. After I added the product from the main page to the cart page. I received the product from the state. That's why item.product

Comment: Sorry, I thought it was clear what I was asking for... What is the ***value*** of `item.product` passed to the handlers?

Comment: @Zein okay wait

Comment: @DrewReese Sorry I'm a beginner. Do you mean I should pass the item inside of the handeler?
like "onClick={(item) => increaseQuantity(product, price....)}" like that?
or the "const increaseQuantity = ( item ) => {...........}"

Comment: No, I was just referring to passing `item` to `increaseQuantity`, i.e. `increaseQuantity(item)` and then destructuring the properties you need. Not really relevant to the issue though.

Comment: @DrewReese Thank you, Man. I think I got what you trying to say. But do you know why exactly am getting this error? 
If I use useState will it be solved? It would be really helpful..

Comment: I don't. I don't see any overt issues with the code, and I think this is a data issue, this is why I asked what the `id` value is or is supposed to be. A running codesandbox that we could inspect live would be helpful. You can mock the data and axios calls.

Comment: Here's the link
https://codesandbox.io/s/name-error-code-pvb4eo

Comment: @DrewReese id is the product.id here. the id value is product id. I mean I'm trying to increase/decrease the amount of the product quantity from the cart page.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, everyone for your comments and view.
I got the solution. Here's in the **CartReducer** code I added **true** instead of the item. this is the solution. Thank you.

```js
if(isItemExist) {
  return {
    ...state,
    cartItems: state.cartItems.map((i) =>
      i.product === isItemExist.product ? item : i
      ),
  }
};
```